# Material Table - nested columns

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Is it possible to make a table with nested columns using `material-table` library?

[Final result that I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REWiu.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible with `material-table` . You have to use Components property to achieve that.

```
function App() {
  const columns = [...];

  const data = [...];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MaterialTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        components={{
          Header: props => {
            return (
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
                    Average A
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell colSpan={2} align="center">
                    Average B
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell align="center">Lower</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">Upper</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">Lower</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">Upper</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
            );
          },
          Row: ({ data }) => {
            return (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.lowerA}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.upperA}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.lowerB}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.upperB}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**DEMO:** [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hawking-sqx1i)

Answer (score 0):

You can use colspan. Check example here.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_colspan